# How to match `.[domain]` for this regex that i have, rather than the first `.`

Tags: regex

Given this URL regex

```
((https?:\/\/?(www\.))?|(www\.))[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._+~#=]{1,256}\.[a-zA-Z0-9()]{1,6}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9()@:%_+.~#?&//=]*)
```

How can I properly make it trigger for the following

```
www.google.com
https://www.google.com
google.com
```

but also make it only trigger after the `.[domain]`

the current regex matches `google.c` but starts to match `www.g` right off the bat

edit: new regex

```
(https:\/\/(www\.)|(www\.))[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._+~#=]{1,256}\.[a-zA-Z0-9()]{1,6}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9()@:%_+.~#?&//=]*)
```

the above regex works as expected for `https://www.google.com` and `www.google.com`, but does not yet work for `google.com`

Comment: What specifically do you want to match with your regex? The domain?

Comment: I just need it to trigger upon the last `.d` where `d` is the beginning of the domain name. If you take this current regex into https://regexr.com/, `www.g` triggers, when i only want it to trigger for `www.google[.c]` <== the `.c`

similar to how if you type in `google.com`, it triggers correctly

when i say trigger, i mean matches

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to remove `\b` and replace `*` with `+`. Also, if you don't want to match `www.google`, this is what needs to be done:

1. `^` - Matches the beginning of the string.
2. `$` - Matches the end of the string.
3. `(?!www)` - Negative lookahead, that excludes the string `www`.

```
^((https?:\/\/?(www\.))?|(www\.))(?!www)[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_+~#=]{1,256}\.[a-zA-Z0-9()]{0,6}([-a-zA-Z0-9()@:%_+.~#?&//=]+)$
```

See result: https://regexr.com/6pmqb

Comment: This technically works, but I need it to only match once the domain is entered, so as soon as `.c` is typed for example, it would match the entire previous string

Comment: I have updated my answer. So now it also matches if you type e.g. `www.google.c`.

Comment: Awesome, if you take `https://www.google.` it matches `www.google.` right away, when it should wait until `.c` is matched and match the entire string, hopefully that makes sense

if you type in this `https://www.google.` it will match `https://[www.google.]`, while it should match `[https://www.google.c]`

Comment: I see. Please check my updated answer.

Comment: How come if you remove the `^` at the beginning it only matches part of the `www`? I don't want it to actually match only the beginning, I want it to match all.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a positive lookahead to assert that what follows is a domain:

```
((https?:\/\/?(www\.))?|(www\.))[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._+~#=]{1,256}\.(?=[a-zA-Z0-9()]{1,6}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9()@:%_+.~#?&\/=]*))[a-zA-Z0-9()]{1,6}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9()@:%_+.~#?&\/=]*)
```

Comment: This doesn't give me what I want, also achieves the same thing as the current regex i have in the OP